# Specify a range of ASCII lowercase chars in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program that takes a char and compares it to see if it's in a range of certain chars. For instance, if the char I get is an `n` I go to state 3, if its a - m or o - z I go to state 4. I'm new to C++ so I'm still learning.

Can I say something like:

```
char c = file.next_char();
...
if (c in 'a'...'m', 'o'...'z')
{
   state = 3;
} else {
   state = 4;
}
```

Comment: _"and compares it to to if it's is in a range of certain chars"_ ?

Comment: Yes, so if c were something like `d` or `t` this would evaluate to true and I would go to state 3, and if I get an `n` this would be false and I go to state 4. Since `d` is between `a` and `m` or `t` is between `o` and `z`.

Comment: Yes. `if (c != 'n')` works fine.

Comment: @KenWhite What does this do? Does the `<>` mean that if `c` is a char that is before or after `n`?

Comment: Um... It means *if c is not equal to 'n'*. So your code would be `if (c != 'n') { state = 3;} else {state = 4;}`. You haven't learned about *not equals* yet? (`<>` is mathematical *not equals*.)

Comment: Oh, I usually see and use `!=` for not equals. I have never seen `<>` before.

Comment: You can compare `char`s with the usual comparison operators – `'a' < 'e'` – and you can combine conditions into one that requires all of them to be true with [logical AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators), `&&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such syntax in C++. The options are:

1. Use a `switch` statement, when the list of values is generally not contiguous, or
2. Convert the list of explicit character values into contiguous ranges into equivalent boolean expressions. As you know, alphabetic characters consist of a contiguous range of octets in ASCII, so your pseudo-code is equivalent to:

   ```
   if ( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'm')
        ||
        (c >= 'o' && c <= 'z'))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ascii (English), you can rely on the fact that all the lower case letters are adjacent. Just check 'a' <= c && c <= 'z'
after ruling out 'n'.

You never said what happens if the state is not one of those, so I left it alone.

```
// 3 and 4 mean nothing. Give your states meaningful names
enum state_type {FirstState, SecondState, ThirdState, FourthState};

state_type state = FirstState;

char c = get_next_char();
if ('n' == c){
    state = FourthState;
} else if ('a' < c && c < 'z'){
    state = ThirdState;
} else {
    // no change?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use a for loop to compare it to see if it's a letter in the first or second range. The code would be something this:

```
    char range1[/*amount in array here*/] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    //Substitute range on line above(the characters in the string)
    for(int i = 0; i <= /*amount in array here*/; i++) {
        if(range1[i] == /*nameoflettervariablehere*/){
             //Code here
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry but I don't know of a more efficient way.